# RegExp текст с кавычками вида "ООО "Рога и копыта"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите выражение которое находило в строке

```
Организация "ООО "Рога и копыта" выдала "левую" справку фирме "Новый совхоз"
```

строки:

```
"ООО "Рога и копыта"
"левую"
"Новый совхоз"
```

вместе с кавычками.

Comment: Определите формальную грамматику, тогда построим. Но афедроном чую, что невозможно. (hint: а если кавычки закрываются фиг знает где?)

Comment: Представьте себе текст:

> Организация "ООО "Рога и копыта" выдала "левую" справку фирме "Новый совхоз". "Рога и копыта" надо закрывать", — подумал Остап.

Откуда алгоритму знать, что от `ООО` до `закрывать` — не одна большая цитата?

Comment: >потому что у автора нет переносов, а у вас есть (ООО которое).
В этом деле, наверное, существенно, простите что не уточнил - мой любой текст, по которому необходимо проходится этим выражением, будет заведомо в одну длинную строку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd) а по моему возможно:

```
preg_match_all('/"(\w*\s+"|:?)(.*?)"/u', $str, $ok);
```

https://ideone.com/3JZcFM

Comment: @lampa: а что с таким текстом:

> Организация "ООО "Рога и копыта" выдала "левую" справку фирме "Новый совхоз". "Рога и копыта" надо закрывать", — подумал Остап.

Comment: @VladD  https://ideone.com/kjQwRe

Comment: @lampa: `"Рога и копыта" надо закрывать"` не поймалось.

Comment: @VladD потому что у автора нет переносов, а у вас есть (ООО которое).

Comment: @lampa: У автора на самом деле конструкция «ООО „Рога и копыта“», которая из-за использования машинописных кавычек превратилась в "ООО "Рога и копыта"", а два экземпляра кавычек подряд редуцировались. У меня симметричный пример: «„Рога и копыта“ надо закрывать» -> ""Рога и копыта" надо закрывать" -> "Рога и копыта" надо закрывать".

Comment: @VladD я думаю стоит дождаться комментария автора.

Comment: @lampa: вот [тут](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8) даже пример есть. И правда, подождём, что скажет ТС.

Comment: Оставил комментарий выше. 
Всем огромное спасибо

Comment: Даже не знаю как написать, чтоб сильно терминологию не коверкать: preg_match_all('/"(\w*\s+"|:?)(.*?)"/u', $str, $ok) отрабатывает - круто! Я так понимаю это выражение относится к PCRE Patterns. Вот только perl-анализатор не проглатывает начальный слеш и конечное /u :( Yfghbvth pltcm http://regexr.com?353vr не работает

Comment: Я бы предложил на конкретном образце текста делать поиск по принципу:  
В совпадение входит все от кавычки справа от которой слово до слова справа от которого кавычка:  

    "\w.*?\w"
Но данный подход провалится на таком тексте:  

    Вася сказал: "У фирмы "Альбатрос" яблок нет". 
Можно немного усложнить выражение, чтобы оно спарсило и такой образец текста, но все это будет мартышкиным трудом. Потому что человек может правильно распарсить такой текст только из-за того, что это не просто набор символов, а слова, имеющие смысловую нагрузку.

Comment: @axiv флаг /u - это юникод. Если в вашем примере будут только латинские буквы - то всё ок. В перле должно быть что-то похожее.